# How to convert this custom upstart job to systemd?

Tags: upstart, services, systemd

I have a custom upstart job that triggers a series of services:

`/etc/init/auto-gateway.conf`:

```
description "Auto-GateWay"
author      "g4gvideo@gmail.com"

emits gw-is-up
emits gw-is-down

start on (net-device-up or net-device-down)

task

script
if route | grep -q "default"; then
    initctl emit -n gw-is-up
else
    initctl emit -n gw-is-down
fi

end script
```

This works works extremely well on laptops that frequently disconnect and connect from networks, or when they sleep & wakeup. It also works on my servers when the network changes.

I am trying to convert this simple upstart job to systemd. My first attempt is:

`/etc/systemd/system/auto-gateway.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Auto-Gateway service
After=network-online.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/auto-gateway
KillMode=process
Restart=always
Type=forking
TimeoutStartSec=infinity

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

`/usr/sbin/auto-gateway:`

```
#!/bin/bash

while true; do

if route | grep "default"; then
    start some services (if not running)
else
    stop some services (if running)
fi

sleep 30
done >/dev/null
```

I find this to be a poor substitute to the upstart version. I dislike the fixed timer, and hard coding the secondary services into auto-gateway.

Is there any way systemd can *monitor* netdev instead?

Thanks

Comment: have you found solution?

Comment: No. I am so disappointed in systemd - it is overly complicated and basically is systemV on steroids. Upstart is much easier and simpler  to use. The only real way to do do this is to write custom scripts in /etc/network/if-up.d/ /etc/network/if-down.d/ and forget about using systemd. Canonical has made a poor desision to switch to  systemd (in my opinion :). Note to  developers: systemd is not suable for laptops and non-enterprise deployments!

Comment: You may try systemd-mailing list or upstart mailing list for help.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because user hasn't signed on in over 6 months and never responded to last comment after his last sign on also > 6 months old. This can be deemed "abandoned question" as per this rule: https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1843/what-to-do-with-abandoned-questions